# typeperf disk write log interpretation

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

When running typeperf utility to get total disk write.

```
typeperf -si 2 "\LogicalDisk(_Total)\Disk write Bytes/sec"
```

I get results in the format

```
"01/11/2019 01:29:40.674","58066.696363"
```

what is the meaning of the 2 values **58066** and **696363** ?

Answer (score 0):

The command: typeperf -si 2 "\LogicalDisk(_Total)\Disk write Bytes/sec",

it means: To display LogicalDisk process counters every two seconds.

I think the value 58066.696363 is defined by system, it means the value of disk write byte is written by us and system on specific time.

And in my test environment, we can see:

[image]

For details we can refer to the following article:

Typeperf

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490960(v=technet.10)